# database table is not updating in postgres when i am using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

i am building CRUD application i am able to read and delete data but i am unable to update data in the database table for the specific route, also when i tried to update data in the table with id 1 its updating the data in all ids

```
app.get('/doctor/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    //console.log(id);
    const data = await doctor.getDoctorById(id);
    res.render('editDoctor', { data });
});
//update doctor
app.post('/doctor/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const id = req.params.id; // Get the 'id' from the URL parameters
    console.log(data);
    console.log(id);
    try {
        await doctor.updateDoctor(data, id); // Pass the 'id' to the updateDoctor function
        res.redirect('/doctor');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error updating patient:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});
// function to update the information
const updateDoctor = async (updatedData) => {
    const { id, name, specialization, contact, appointment } = updatedData;
    const query = `
    UPDATE doctor
    SET name = $2, specialization = $3, contact = $4, appointment = $5
    WHERE id = $1`;
    const values = [id, name, specialization, contact, appointment]; // Correct order of values
    await pool.query(query, values);
};
```

i am using ejs in front end , i am expecting that the existing doctor information should update with this code but i am receiving the data but its not updating in the database.

Comment: Whatever `pool.query` is (it's generally helpful to tell people what libraries you are using) it should have a means to (a) test if the query was successful and (b) report any errors with it. Use that feature!

Comment: hey i am using     "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "pg-promise": "^11.5.4" and "pg-pool": "^3.6.1", please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 app.post('/doctor/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const updatedData = req.body;
    try {
        await doctor.updateDoctor(id, updatedData);
        res.redirect('/doctor');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error updating doctor:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});
  
const updateDoctor = async (id, updatedData) => {
            const { name, specialization, contact, appointment } = updatedData;
            const query = `
                UPDATE doctor
                SET name = $2, specialization = $3, contact = $4, appointment = $5
                WHERE id = $1`;
            const values = [id, name, specialization, contact, appointment];
            await pool.query(query, values);
        };
```

Comment: hey, its working thank you very much i need something more with it, can you help me with that

Answer (score -1):

Try with out backticks for const query and try to add excpeiton handling block for query method execution i.e, (error, results) => {} . Example given below

i.e.,

```
const updateUser = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
  const { name, email } = request.body

  pool.query(
    'UPDATE users SET name = $1, email = $2 WHERE id = $3',
    [name, email, id],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error"+error);
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).send(`User modified with ID: ${id}`)
    }
  )
}
```